# Error while importing multiple csv's into Mongodb through command line

Tags: windows, mongodb, csv, cmd, mongoimport

I'm trying to import all `csv` files in a folder into those many `MongoDB` collections (with same names as the file names). I'm trying to do it through command line (`mongo.exe`).

I've written the following `for loop` but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
>FOR /R %G in (filepath\...\NYSE\*.csv) DO mongoimport --d nyseDb --c %G --type csv --file %G --headerline
```

The following error was showed up.

```
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical @(shell):1:16
```

I've looked up many places to find corrections, but none of them worked.

Comment: Doesn't `FOR /R %G in (filepath\...\NYSE\*.csv) do echo %G` issue the entire path to file in the output? Given that you are passing that value as a "collection name" to `mongoimport` I'm certain you don't want that. Surely you just want the "base" file name without the ".csv" file extention. As a basic principle `/r` which means recursive seems dangerous in this context as well.

Comment: Always quote paths in `FOR` loops. `"%~G"` Also, do any of your .csv file names contain parentheses characters?